# Orthogonal contrasts, ANOVA, why are there only as many contrasts there are degrees of freedom?

Tags: anova, degrees-of-freedom, contrasts, orthogonal

For example, if I have the data

$$
\begin{array}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
A     & low      &     & medium   &     & high     &     \\ \hline
B     & standard & new & standard & new & standard & new \\ \hline
means & m1       & m2  & m3       & m4  & m5       & m6
\end{array}
$$

And I want to create contrasts, then apparently there are 5 that can be created.

$$
\begin{align}
C_1 &: \text{New v Standard} \\
C_2 &: \text{Low v High} \\
C_3 &: \text{(Low and High) v Medium} \\
C_4 &: \text{Interaction between $C_1$ and $C_2$} \\
C_5 &: \text{Interaction between $C_1$ and $C_3$} \\
\end{align}
$$

If I create the additional contrast

$$
C_6 : \text{Medium v High}
$$

What has been violated?

I don't really understand why this isn't an option.

## Why there are only five

From my notes, with respect to the table provided, all I have to explain this is the following

*Since the treatments occupy a six-dimensional vector space, it is only possible
to find six orthogonal vectors. One of these dimensions is occupied by the
overall mean:*

$$
C_0 = \left[ 1 \quad 1 \quad 1 \quad 1 \quad 1 \quad 1 \right]
$$

*Hence there will only be 5 orthogonal contrasts - one for each treatment degree
of freedom.*

Comment: Nothing has been "violated:" $C_6$ is a perfectly fine contrast.  In what sense is it "not an option"?  Perhaps you are using an unusual definition of "contrast"?

Comment: "Apparently" is a bit mysterious. To whom is it apparent? You can create an infinite number of contrasts - most won't make much sense, but you can create them.

Comment: sorry for the mystery - I've added some more information, hopefully that clears it up

Comment: @whuber but it couldn't be included as well as the rest presumably? I can't have c1 to c5 *and* c6, ? This is the impression that I have been given at least

Comment: @PeterFlom is there actually an infinite amount that can be created from an initially set of 5 means? I've added some more information, hopefully that clears it up some what

Comment: Sure. You could contrast twice new minus three times standard. There can only be 5 that are orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 2):

There are only 5 that are all orthogonal to each other. But you can have different sets of 5. Your proposed 6th contrast is not orthogonal to the other 5, but if you drop one of those 5, then you can add it.

See [this post](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~cpd/anovas/datasets/Orthogonal%20contrasts.htm) from University of Southampton which gives examples of the different possible sets of contrasts for factors with different numbers of levels (they stop with 5 levels, but the idea is the same).